# How can I share session between a Sitecore instance and an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: session-state

Currently we have one Sitecore instance using Sitecore Redis Session State Provider, `Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider`, and another ASP.NET MVC application using Microsoft Redis Session State Provider, `Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider`.

What would be the ways for both applications to share the same session state?

So far, we could think of two approachs:

1. ASP.NET MVC application using `Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider`.
2. Sitecore instance using `Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider`.

As both Redis Session State Provider share the same interface, at a first glance, it should not be an issue.